# Linq involving groupby orderby and join

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables

```
tblEquipment            
Id1 Id2 Version1 Version2         
1    1     -        0          
2    1     A        1            
3    1     B        1         
4    1     B        2         
5    2     -        0                                               
6    2     A        0
```

and another table

```
tblHistory                 
IdParent     Version1    Version2        Date             
1               -           0           1/01/14            
1               A           1           2/01/14              
1               B           1           3/01/14              
1               B           2           4/01/14                 
2               -           0           4/01/14                
2               A           0           6/01/14           
2               A           0           8/01/14
```

I am trying to write a query that fetches the record which has the maximum Version1 and Version2 corresponding to the maximum version1. For e.g. I want the following records from the above table -

`Id2 = 1`, `Version1 = B`, `Version2 = 2` and `Date = 4/01/14`
`Id2 = 2`, `Version1 = A`, `Version2 = 0` and `Date = 8/01/14`

Can anyone help me with the linq that gives me the above result.

Comment: or Id1 in tblHistory should be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

Comment: @GrantWinney Yes..its Id2. I made a mistake in the question. Also, I am very new to c# so excuse me if it is a stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetching data according the rule you described would be like this:

```
var result = history
            .GroupBy( h => h.IdParent )
            .Select( h => h.OrderBy( h1 => h1.Version1 )
                             .ThenBy( h2 => h2.Version2 )
                             .Last() )
            .Select(h => new { 
                        Id2 = h.IdParent, 
                        Version1 = h.Version1, 
                        Version2 = h.Version2, 
                        Date = h.Date 
                        } 
            );
```

Comment: I have corrected the mistake in my question.                          How can i link the tblHistory with this and get the last modified date.?

Comment: Are those tables linked on DB level by foreign keys at all?

Comment: No. Its just that tblHistory has two more columns Version1 and Version2 and the records are identified where IdParent = Id2.

Comment: `OrderBy(h => h.Date).Last().Date` could be written simply `Max(h => h.Date)`.

Comment: If tblHistory also has Version1 and Version2 columns and IdParent has Id2 column values then you don't need to join those two tables. I've adjusted the query accordingly.

Comment: when I debugg the code, and see the values in result, it gives an exception saying "LINQ to Entities doesnot recognise the method Last[tblEquipment]".
However, when I modify the query to  equipment
            .GroupBy( e => e.Id2 )
            .Select( e => e.OrderByDescending( e1 => e1.Version1 )
                             .ThenByDescending( e2 => e2.Version2 )
                             .FirstOrDefault() )
It works. What can be the reason for this.?